# Why is Scrapy not returning the entire HTML code?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to convert my selenium web scraper to scrapy because selenium is nor mainly intended for web scraping.

I just started writing it and have already hit a roadblock. My code is below.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from pathlib import Path

max_price = "110000"
min_price = "65000"
region_code = "5E430"

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%" + region_code + "&minBedrooms=2&maxPrice=" + max_price + "&minPrice=" + min_price + "&propertyTypes=detached" + \
        "%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=sharedOwnership%2Cretirement&furnishTypes=&keywords="

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        work_path = "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/Scrapy_ROI_work_area/"
        no_of_pages = response.xpath('//span[@class = "pagination-pageInfo"]').getall()
        with open(Path(work_path, "test.txt"), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        with open(Path(work_path, "extract.txt"), 'wb') as g:
            g.write(no_of_pages)
        self.log('Saved file test.txt')

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start()
```

My roadblock is response.body does not contain the element sought by the xpath expression //span[@class = "pagination-pageInfo"] but the website does have it. I am way out of my depth with the inner workings of websites and am not a programmer by profession....unfortunately. Would anyone help me understand what is happening please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand first that there is a big difference in what you are watching in your browser, against what is actually sent to you by the server.

The server, appart from the HTML, most of the times is sending you JavaScript code that has influence over the HTML itself at runtime.

For example, the first GET you do to a page, it can give you an empty table and some JavaScript code. That code then is in charge of hitting a database and filling the table. If you try to scrape that site with Scrapy alone it will fail to get the table because Scrapy does not have a JavaScript engine able to parse the code.

This is your case here, and will be your case for most of the pages you will try to crawl.

You need something to render the code in the page. The best option for Scrapy is Splash:

https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash

Which is a headless and scriptable browser you can use with a Scrapy plugin. It's mantained by Scrapinghub (the creators of Scrapy), so it will work pretty good.

Comment: How did you know it was sending JavaScript code? How can I pick up on these things? :(

Comment: With time you will learn. The advice I can give you is that you try to understand how the site works. For that the Developer Tools of your favorite browser is enough. Try to check the Network traffic. Understand what requests are done by the site after you hit that F5 button. A lot of the times, if possible, it's better to use the sites API directly instead of parsing the HTML. For this site in particular I entered the URL you have in your code and saw that the page is pretty modern, so, 101% is full javascript.